# How to connect to wifi after toggling the wifi card into monitor mode

Tags: networking, kali-linux, monitoring, posix

After running (1)`sudo airmon-ng check list` and (2)`airmon-ng start <Iface>`. I cannot come back to the original `managed` mode of the wifi interface. I am currently using: Kali 2022.3.

(1). Kill any process/service that is currently using any wireless interface.

(2). Start the 'monitor' mode in the Iface interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restarting the network service, solved the problem.

run: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: comments are better for resolving issues with the edit, rather than flags. @GAD3R's edit looks good to me, but can you explain how it breaks the code? I know that other service managers such as `service` expected the verb after the service name, such as `service network restart`, but I believe the edited systemctl format is correct.

Comment: The original one, works fine as well. There was no need of any modification. Why the platform do not ask the creator of the post before editing? What if someone makes some edition introducing malicious code? In this particular case, it is the same.

Comment: Ahhh, I mis-read the edit; sorry about that! The original was `sudo NetworkManager restart` which appears to place `NetworkManager` as the command. Kali is based on Debian, and https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager says the restart command would be `sudo service network-manager restart`, although I suspect recent Kali & Debian systems would use systemd and thus `systemctl`. The [systemctl syntax](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#) is `systemctl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [UNIT...]`, which would translate to `systemctl restart NetworkManager` as GAD3R wrote.

Comment: The original command `sudo start NetworkManager` work but it is deprecated, it is used on Upstart init systems.